# Filemaker - how/where to use custom function?

Tags: function, filemaker

I have downloaded the BaseElements plugin for Filemaker and managed to get it installed, I have downloaded this specifically to make use of "BE_ExportFieldContents" (https://baseelementsplugin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204700538-BE-ExportFieldContents) which basically allows me to export from a Container field on a server side script. I have looked through the documentation and cannot seem to find help.

Now I have the function, I'm completely at a loss on how to actually call the function? I want to export something from the container file to the filemaker documents path - so my question is, where and how the hell do I use this function in Filemaker? Apologies in advance for the noob question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a script where you call this function from the record in question. This script can be run in the client, or via a schedule on FileMaker Server or via the Perform Script on Server script step.
The syntax is like this:

> BE_ExportFieldContents ( field ; outputPath )

Where the ‘field’ parameter is the container field and the ‘outputPath’ is where you want the file to end up.

Usually you call such functions via the Set Variable script step. After the execution the variable contains any error or result from the call.

Note that the plugin needs to be installed and enabled on the server for it to work there.

Comment: Thankyou for the swift response, I understand how to write the parameters, but in the script, what step do I use to call the function? Do I use "Set Field" for example and set the field as the custom function with my parameters or something? Like where in the script do I type the custom function?

Comment: Use the Set Variable script step as I said.

Comment: Thankyou Andreas, I am getting an error code 13 when using the BE GetLastError, just trying to find a reference docs so I can check what error this is!

Comment: Did you install plugin on the server or on the desktop?

Comment: The BE_GetLastError returns errors from the libraries that the plugin use, so it’s not always straight forward to know which library is throwing the error. From experience, it is easy to mess up the path. The plugin wants a system path, not a FileMaker path, so check that. Also check that the path is writable. There are a couple of custom functions on the net somewhere that converts between these paths to make it easier to target FileMaker paths using the plugin.

Comment: Seems error 13 on a file operation is a permission issue. Check this article. https://baseelementsplugin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203885818-File-Permissions-when-running-under-FMS